# What's the "correct" way for a web app (WAR file) to read and write configuration data outside of the WAR (without using a database)?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, war

I have web app (in a WAR file) that has a small number of configuration fields that can be specified by the user in the web ui.

So the webapp needs to read the configuration info, and also write the configuration info.

I don't want to connect to a database to read/write data that way because I don't want the extra setup and configuration.

Ideally, I want the web app to just read and write an XML file (which lives outside of the WAR file).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing stopping a Java web application from writing anywhere on the machine on which it is deployed.  What is the actual problem, and have you tried something yet?

Comment: Thanks ... googling I see that I can get the actual file location of the WAR file by using `String webAppPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");` ... I guess that means I can simply create a folder and write a file under /tomcat/conf/myapp/ ... but that assumes the tomcat process is running as a user who has permission to create that folder and file.  Am still wondering ... is there a "more correct" way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The Java Security Manager can prevent writing anywhere on the machine. The default place for storing files is the temporary directory (java.io.tmpdir) but you don't want it to be cleaned during a restart or another action on the server.